# Avoiding Alert: Do Not Use the Development Server

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi

When running locally I get this message:
WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
Use a production WSGI server instead.

I want to make sure it's not running on production.
I run flask over uWSGI and nginx - started from here: (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uswgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04)

My .ini file runs wsgi.py file and in it I have:
'''app.run()'''.

When I run this wsgi.py file directly I still see this message. But when starting it from .ini file I don't. So i'm not sure it's fine, or that I just don't see the warning

Answer (score 1):

Running from an INI file won´t give errors.